# JQuery: Check if jquery plugin is already called

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have build a jQuery plugin who needs to be 'closed' before it can be called again, so I need to check if the jQuery plugin is called (active).
I know I could save a value with jQuery.data() and simply remove/reset it when the plugin closes but is there another or smarter way?

Comment: Using data is what [jQuery suggests](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)... storing object literals.

Comment: I see. Just thought that there would be a 'smarter' way when I wanted to check if the plugin was instantiated at all and not like they suggest, on a per element basis.

Comment: have you considered marking an answer or leaving a comment as to whether anything helped you?

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof $.fn.my_func !== "undefined"
```

Comment: Have you tested that? 

typeof $.fn.my_func will always be function in my case. I'm NOT interested in if the plugin exists

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I'm confused by what you mean by 'closed'?

Comment: Basically when a plugin runs, he wants to be a flag available so that he can logically decide weather another instance of a function should be able to executed on an element.

Comment: `typeof jQuery.cookie !== "undefined"` helped me to see if cookie plugin is already included

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know if the plugin is active use a global variable like so:

```
$.fn.my_func(params)
{
    if(window.my_func_active)
    {
        console.log('Cannot run plugin');
        return;
    }

    window.my_func_active = true;
    //blah
    endme = function()
    {
       //shutdown here
       delete window.my_func_active;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really. Its kind of the same solution I suggested with jQuery.data().
Is there a way you can check if a plugin is instantiated?

Comment: Upvoted your question because im stumped and this looks interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, interesting case.
You can consider using jQuery's queues..

```
var n = $('someSpecialDiv').queue("specialQue");

$('someSpecialDiv').queue("specialQue", function () {
    $.myPlugin();  //Always run your plugin(only this plugin) after queueing to this queue
  });

  alert(n.length); //This would tell you if your function is in execution if > 0
```

I'm not sure whether this helps your case?